# Jira filter sorted so that my issues come first

Tags: jira, jql

I want to write a filter in Jira that includes issues assigned to several users, but the ones assigned to me first (specifically in this case a filter of issues likely to be relevant for the stopwatch time tracker).

I don't know how to do this in JQL.  if I was doing it in SQL I would do either:

```
select *
from jira
where condition_one or condition_two
order by decode(assignee, current_user, 1, 0) desc,
other_sort_field
```

or, even better (since i could effectively sort by sub-filter):

```
select *
from jira
where condition_one 
order other_sort_field
union all
select *
from jira
where condition_two
order other_sort_field
```

Is it possible to do anything like this in JQL?  i haven't found anything?

Comment: FWIW, I have this question too, in my case since context is apparently absolutely everything, it's for a display on a dashboard. I want my issues ranked higher in my priority queue, but not to the exclusion of all others.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with this filter?

1. If showing on a **sprint/kanban board** you could use different [swim lanes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/jira-agile-user-s-guide/configuring-a-board/configuring-swimlanes) to show yourself and then other users
2. Is showing on a **dashboard** consider having 2 different saved filters and show both using separate [Filter results gadgets](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira064/adding-the-filter-results-gadget-720416922.html).

In both cases the JQL used could be of the form:

```
assignee in (user1, user2, user3) and status != closed order by assignee
```

will show alphabetically by user

Comment: As I said,  my use case is a filter to populate the suggested issues drop down in the jira stopwatch helper app.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your question to reflect that, I have no sense that that is what you are referring to.